# create BI report in fusion using fusion webservices

Tags: web-services, soapui, bi-publisher, fusion, oracle-fusion-apps

I have consumed BI Report through WSDL, I have checked in SOAP UI there is a method to create BI Report through WSDL.

How can i create BI Report through WSDL?.Kindly help me

Regards
Suba

Answer (score 0):

To create a BIPublisher report, you need a report template, and a datamodel. You can either place the template on the BIP server, and pass `templateFileName` in the `createReport` method. Or if you want to send the template in SOAP, you will have to Base64 encode it and send that data in `templateData`.

You will have to provide `folderAbsolutePathURL` , that will the path where the report will be saved. And `dataModelURL`, pointing to the datamodel for this report. The datamodel has to be created manually on the server.

The other parameters are optional. Its all documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPDV/reportservice.htm#BIPDV335).

Comment: Thanks Ranjith for your prompt Response,I need to create BI Report in HCM Fusion using ADF page.Currently I am consuming BI Report, to get fusion details.I have a requirement to create a new BI Report in Fusion, by passing the values through ADF Page.Is DataModel manditory to create BI Report?

Comment: In my case, the details i get from the ADF page, need to add row in Generated BI Report

Comment: Well yes, all BIP reports will have a datamodel in it. Try creating a BIP report first in HCM BIP to get an idea of this. createReport only creates a new report, you have to use runReport to actually run a created report. I think in your case, you can create a BIP report manually first, and then use runReport to run that report. You can send the input data in base64 form in runReport.  This has been answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558070/call-bi-publisher-web-service-with-reportrawdata